# Internet intermittent after blue screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, internet

I am using windows 7, and have had great internet connection. While I was in the middle of running a game, I bumped my USB speaker system, which caused a blue screen error. After I restarted my computer some of my USB ports were not working and my internet connection is very strange, it can connect but will drop after about 1min, then take another 5mins or so to connect, all other PCs on the network are fine. I considered a system restore, but I have no restore points.

Any ideas how to fix it? does it sound like a software or hardware issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out for certain whether it is a hardware issue by booting up with a Live Linux distribution (like Knoppix) and seeing whether your ports still port.

http://knoppix.net/

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

If the problem is electronic then I'd venture to say that a professional laptop technician may be your best bet. Laptops are tightly packaged and specialised making them difficult to tear apart let alone repair (though it is possible. The biggest problem in this case is narrowing down to where exactly the problem is. In this case, likely internal USB hub and (possibly another core chip) which means particular chips are malfunctioning (fixing difficult because of acccess difficulties and soldering may be required to replace/fix chip). One possibility is removing all port from system and then seeing whether functionality returns to normal after that).